treeview динамическое заполнение из файла
Продолжаю разбираться с Treeview. Подскажите есть ли возможность заполнить его по мере появления новых записей в файле? На данный момент решил пока так: - очищаем Treeview потом заново полностью читаем файл и заполняем Treeview. Файл не будет более 200 строк.
tree = ttk.Treeview(Form, columns=("winner", "loss", "time_p", "time_v", "tatami")                
tree.column("winner", width=300, anchor=tk.W)
tree.column("loss", width=300, anchor=tk.W)
tree.column("time_p", width=120, anchor=tk.CENTER)
tree.column("time_v", width=120, anchor=tk.CENTER)
tree.column("tatami", width=120, anchor=tk.CENTER)

while ww:
    time.sleep(20)
    for item in tree.get_children():
        tree.delete(item)

    with open("\\log.csv", newline="", encoding='utf-8') as f:
         for Ushatniki in csv.reader(f):                    
             tree.insert("", tk.END, values=Ushatniki)                        
             child_id = tree.get_children()[-1]
             tree.focus(child_id)
             tree.selection_set(child_id)
             tree.see(child_id)
    tree.bind("TreeviewSelect")        
    tree.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True) 


Зачем дерево? Где иерархия в данных?

Treeview в части энергозатрат на программирование не лучше и не хуже других вариантов. Особенно если после надо будет работать с конкретной записью. Пример: список файлов в каталоге. Treeview не обязательно делать и одноколоночным.
